# Reference request, statistical inference

Tags: statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, estimation, hypothesis-testing

Good morning,

I'm looking for a good reference for study on statistical inference, the main topics that will study are

- Tests of Hypotheses
- Interval estimation

I recommend taking a look at

- [Mood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070854653)
- [Casella](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)

These books are good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casella is pretty standard. Haven't dealth with Mood. However, have you considered [Hogg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321795431) or [DeGroot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500466) or, for a more practical bent, [Devore](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538733527)

Answer (score 1):

The list from @Bey is excellent. Devore has some excellent engineering examples and maybe the most modern approach. Hogg & Craig and Wackerly, Mendenhall & Scheaffer are a little more elementary than Hogg, Casella or DeGroot. Mood is excellent, with many challenging and extraordinarily rewarding problems.

For self study you should probably pick a book with some answers in the back. Maybe some of us could give you better advice if you say
something about your math background and your objectives. Anyhow, here's wishing you success and many intriguing hours of exploration.

Comment: Which book by Devore are you referring to? He has several.

Comment: [Math Stat by Devore and Berk](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461403906) may be most relevant for theory. Engr Stat book also good.