# Probability theory required for learning statistics rigorously

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I would like to learn statistics rigorously. The only book that I can find that seems to do statistics rigorously is this book "Theory of statistics" by Schervish (which seems advanced):

[http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Statistics-Springer-Series/dp/0387945466](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387945466)

**Question 1:** Are there other books that do statistics rigorously (and theoretically do not assume prior knowledge of statistics) ?

I took only an introductory non-rigorous course called "Probability and Statistics" that is taught for engineers at my university. I know analysis. I know some measure theory. I plan to finish the book measure theory by Halmos which has a chapter on probability theory (I'm currently self-studying it).

**Question 2:** If I finish the book measure theory by Halmos, will my background in probability theory be sufficient to learn the book "Theory of Statistics" by Schervish ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312087/reference-request-statistical-inference/1312453#1312453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know analysis including measure theory, you should be able to read Schervish.  I don't recall that there's that much measure theory in it.  You do need to know how to write mathematical arguments.

**PS:** I'm realizing deGroot & Schervish is what I had in mind when I wrote the answer above.  Maybe I'll add more later.  See comments below.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You seem to be an expert in statistics so I trust your answer a lot. By the way, do you have any other suggestions for books that do statistics rigorously ?

Comment: Perhaps Lehman's _Theory of Point Estimation_ and _Theory of Hypothesis Testing_.  Serfling's _Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics_ is rigorous but it doesn't do the usual theory-of-statistics topics found in something like deGroot & Schervish.  And now suddenly I'm realizing deGroot & Schervish is what I had in mind when I wrote the answer above.  Probably something can be said for Bickel & Doksum, although I seem to recall being annoyed by the fact that they didn't assume the reader knows matrix algebra.